# How to prove that two convex functions have the same minimizer?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am looking for a general method to show that two convex functions have the same minimizer. That is, for a pair of arbitrary convex functions $f$ and $g$, I want to know when it is possible to show that

$x^* = \text{argmin}_x f(x) = \text{argmin}_x g(x)$

Is this possible? Others have asked this kind of question, but they always asked about a specific pair of functions, and the answers they got were fairly specific: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962782/show-that-two-functions-have-the-same-minimizer) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946541/how-can-we-show-that-two-different-optimization-problems-have-the-same-minimizer). What I am looking for is a general answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the generality level you are looking for with your question. I suppose that it is pretty difficult to say something *in general*, but if you are looking for a simple criterion, then I think immediately at the following:

Let $f$, $g$ two convex real-valued functions. If you can show that $f$ can be obtained from $g$ composing $g$ with a strictly increasing function $h$, then the minimizer of $f = h \circ g$ and $g$ is going to be the same.

Comment: This is helpful in principle, but even in simple cases it seems like it introduces difficulties. For example, how can $f(x) = \sum_i|x_i|$ be obtained from $g(x) = \sum_ix_i^2$ (or $g$ from $f$) by some strictly increasing function $h$?

Comment: Not true in general. Suppose to have $f(x)= e^{e^{x^2}}$ and $g(x)=x^2$, then you are sure they both share a minimum point in $x=0$ just because you see immediately that you can reach $g$ from $f$ applying twice the logarithmic function.